# Node PKG fails to build executable from app that uses EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a Node application (HTTP server) which uses express and EJS for rendering templates. When I try to build an executable standalone file with pkg (https://github.com/zeit/pkg), it raises an error stating that ejs is not installed as soon as I try to access 'localhost/'. But the original app runs normally, and EJS is installed as another module apart from express.

The docs point out that dependencies are taken into account when building the .exe. I could see it works, because requests for caching database with mysql module are happening normally. This seems to be a problem specific to EJS, maybe because it is not 'require()d' but selected as template engine in express options.

As simple as it may be, has anyone ran into something like this? I googled out but found nothing related to errors in ejs after projects are built with pkg.

stack trace:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:592:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1280:46)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:518:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1159:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at new View (C:\snapshot\Eduardo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (C:\snapshot\Eduardo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\snapshot\Eduardo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\snapshot\Eduardo\Desktop\node eureka\app.js:0:0
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm running into this same problem. Will report back if I can find something.

Comment: Not yet. I ignored de pkg creation and used a full node environment, but I must remove part of the code I want to protect from the front-end developer.

Comment: I already solved this. At this point I don't remember what gave me the error in the first place to be honest. (It seems like in my mind two days is really a trip to the past, lol, sorry) What I did at the end is include the views as a express.static files in the app configuration. In the package.json I specify that I'm using whatever is in public and in my views folder. Will post in answer because it's too long of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use EJS with PKG I just ended up changing some configuration in my files.

In `app.js` I just ended up adding the `views` folder as a static resource.

app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views'))); // Line exists just for PKG
```

In `package.json` you need to specify your assets and the starting point.

package.json:

```
...
"main": "app.js",
"bin": "app.js",
...
"pkg": {
    "assets": ["views/**/*", "public/**/*"]
  }
```

And more importantly in my opinion, because this ended up giving me a headache, when compiling using PKG you need to specify that you are compiling the whole project in the folder, as it needs to find the `package.json` file and go from there to see what it needs.

Using:
`pkg .`

I was getting the error you posted when I was compiling using just `pkg app.js`, and using `pkg .` instead, fixed the problem for the most part. Technically you could skip the changes in `app.js` but that modification ensures that the `views` folder is included in the binary, as just adding it in the `package.json` file in the `assets` section seems to not work at all by itself. (Also, note that the use of `path.join` is necessary)