# Nodejs project executable

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make my nodejs application to be executable, and here is a code snippet from app.js ;

```
const express = require('express');
const async = require("async");
const fs = require('fs');
const { forEach } = require('lodash');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.listen(5500, () => {
  console.log("listening.");
});

process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/images'));


app.use(express.static('/'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get('/main',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile('./entry.html', { root: __dirname });
   
});
```

The entry.html is not in any folder, directly in the same location as app.js.
It works on my local host.

However, when I try to pack app.js (pkg app.js), it gives this error ;

Error: File or directory 'C:**\new_nodejs\entry.html' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
at error_ENOENT (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:657:19)

What can I do ?

Some sources say, it's because of __dirname , but I could not fix it.

Comment: you need to add it as assets. explain how do you build the executable and i can help you how to add it as assets

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: in my answer i build it through `package.json` and not directly running pkg from command line. its not so different. but its easy to edit it through package.json instead of parameters in command line which not support all options. any way you can change it to way you build the application

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok (except for require unused packages :-) ). anyway you need to add it as assets.
for example lets say you code above is in `main.js` and you have `entry.html` in the same location. edit your `package.json` like below (of course change what you need to fit you needs)

```
...
 "scripts": {
    "pkg": "pkg ."
  },
  "bin": "main.js",
  "pkg": {
    "assets": "./entry.html"
  }
...
```

now build your app with `npm run pkg` and its should contain `entry.html` file and return it

Comment: yea, now the entry page coming up however, I have other htmls and .ejs files in my project ?

Comment: you can change the line `"assets": "./entry.html"` to include what every you want. its glob pattern so change it to what ever you want. `assets` also can accept array with glob pattern strings

Comment: for example if you want all the `.ejs` and `.html` files in the current directory or some where else in subdirectories you can write `"assets": [ "./**/*.html","./**/*.ejs"]`. you can add what ever you want

Comment: It's fine for .html's, but when I try to open .ejs It says "Cannot find module 'ejs' . This is how I write assets : "assets": ["./entry.html","./addCustomerPage.html","./views/whouseEntryejs.ejs","./views/whouseExitejs.ejs"]

Comment: its inclues those files but had problem to require ejs. please look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988579/pkg-with-axios-1-x-cant-be-compiled/76988695#76988695 its can help you with this case here. also your problem looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55329158/node-pkg-fails-to-build-executable-from-app-that-uses-ejs

Comment: It says :/ , Warning Cannot resolve 'mod'
  C:\Users\PC\Desktop\new_nodejs\dist\index.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.

Comment: do you use dynamic require? if so its wont work and that maybe the reason pkg complain about ejs from the first place

Comment: When I execute the index, now it just opens .ejs files